# Cant get ruby 1.9.3 to install get requested URL does not exist

Tags: ruby, rvm

When running the following command:

```
rvm install 1.9.3
```

I get the following output:

> Error: the requested URL does not exist: 
>   ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-.tar.bz2

I have updated rvm to the latest and typed `rvm reload`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to install by explicitly stating the desired patch level: `rvm install 1.9.3-p194`

Answer (score 17):

The URL should have been something like:
ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-**p194**.tar.bz2

Try updating your rvm by

```
rvm get head
```

and then install 1.9.3 by

```
rvm install 1.9.3
```